# Centering rotated paragraph inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Zrx7/2/

```
.events{
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
.tt_username{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.tt_username p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    background: #ff0000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I need to center the text inside the grey div, this div's height is consistent, but the text is generated via ajax, for this reason I believe transform origin is not going to fix it. Would like a CSS solution, but welcome js as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `display: table`, combined with `display: table-cell` as well as `vertical-align: middle`:

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Zrx7/3/

```
.events{
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
    display: table; /*added*/
}
.tt_username{
    /* position: absolute;*/
    top:0px;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;  /*added*/
    vertical-align:middle; /*added*/
}

.tt_username p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    background: #ff0000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```